# How to stop for loop from iterating when condition is successfully met?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm working on Hand Cricket script & i want to stop "for" loop from iterating when a user's choice of number & CPU's choice of number are equal & if it's unequal it should keep iterating until it doesnt reach the final range's value

```
for i in range(1,7):
    print("Ball %d"%i)
    user_choice =int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 6 --> "))
    cpu_choice=random.randint(1,6)

    if user_choice < 7:
        print("CPU picked --> ",cpu_choice)
        run=cpu_choice+run

    if user_choice == cpu_choice:
        print("User is OUT!!")
        run -= cpu_choice
        print("Runs = %d \t Over = %d.%d\n"%(run,i//6,i%6))
        break
        print("Runs = %d \t Over = %d.%d\n"%(run,i//6,i%6))

    else:
        print("\nWRONG CHOICE!! %d ball is cancelled.\n"%i)
        break
```

Comment: It looks like you've already done that with the `break`.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `if user_choice  == cpu_choice: break`, this question is pretty basic, and you're already using `break` in the code above, hence curious as to why this wasn't easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something in your question, but it looks like you've already got it. `break` will force the `for` loop to exit. So if you wrap your break-statement in a conditional gate (`if` statement), you can set the criteria that must be met for the break.

Something like this comes to mind:

```py
# Calculate the CPU's Random Integer ONCE
cpu_choice=random.randint(1,6)

# Iteratively Ask User for Input and Validate
for i in range(1,7):
    # Capture Input from User
    user_choice =int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 6 --> "))
    # Verify Input in Specific Range
    if user_choice not in range(1,7):
        print("{} is not in the valid range. Try again.".format(user_choice))
    else:
        # Check if User Input Matches CPU's Selection
        if user_choice == cpu_choice:
            print("You've got the right number! The number was: {}".format(user_choice))

            break  # break out of the `for` loop!

        # Not Correct Input from User
        else:
            print("{} is not the correct number. Try again.".format(user_choice))
```

Again, it seems like you've already come to this answer in a way. Are you asking something else instead?

Comment: Sorry for causing inconvenience there were actually 2 different cases & this was 1st case in which I added break but I forgot adding break in 2nd loop that's why I couldnt get the desired result. Thanks for the help & apologies for wasting time.

Comment: @AkshatKulshreshtha, no worries! Hope it helped!